# How to add a loop into a listbox items that contains values?

Tags: vb.net

[DESIGN here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPKaP.png)

I'm trying to add a certain amount to the loan when the list or lists on the listbox is selected each items in the listbox have differ or same amount. i want the code to work even if i didn't have to choose or highlight any of the item in the listbox.

```
'Extra Sevices
        Dim extra As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItem.count
            If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "insurance - O" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Hotel discount -O" Then
                extra = 500
            ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "One payment grace -F" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "2-day late payment-F" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Frequent Borrowe benefits -F" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Online reversals -F" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "GST waver -F" Then
                extra = 500
            ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Face to face transactions -S" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Saturday visits -S" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Face to face consultations -S" Or
                    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Phone reminders -S" Then
                extra = 200
            Else
                extra = 0
            End If

            extra = extra + extra

        Next
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your title should summarize the problem, not a collection of words which may or may not be related in some way to what you think the issue is.  A clear concise problem statement and question would help too.

Comment: ... and please stop yelling in all-caps and lay off the whining.

Comment: How is your current configuration NOT working?

Comment: sorry, kind of desperate here

Answer (score 0):

You have a few minor issues in your code

```
'Extra Sevices

Dim i As Integer
Dim extra As Integer
Dim value as Integer

extra = 0
For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.count - 1
    value = 0
    '-> This line of code answered the ORIGINAL question
    '  Select case Listbox1.SelectedItem
    '-> This line of code answeres your question in the comments
    Select case Listbox1.SelectedItem(i)
        Case "insurance - O", "Hotel discount -O"
            value = 500
        Case "One payment grace -F", "2-day late payment-F", "Frequent Borrowe benefits -F", "Online reversals -F", "GST waver -F"
            value = 500
        Case "Face to face transactions -S", "Saturday visits -S", "Face to face consultations -S", "Phone reminders -S"
            value = 200
    End Select
    extra = extra + value
Next
```

This should fix them and you can compare the code to yours.

The main point is the loop, you end at COUNT, the list is zero based so it's count -1

Comment: Its still didnt work, the 
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItem.count - 1 gets highlighted saying "System.nullreferenceexception"

Comment: yeah i forgot to DIM i sorry just add the line "Dim i as integer"

Comment: actually it does work i just had to change Listbox1.SelectedItems.Count

Comment: Yeah its been so long since i have not done vb i forgot lots hahaha

Comment: but now another problem occurs. when i run the code the calculation somehow wrong. when i choose more than one it only adding the amount of which the 1st item i chose. e.g when i choose O = 500 next S = 200 it became 500+500 instead 500 +200

Comment: change the line "Select case Listbox1.SelectedItem" to "Select case Listbox1.SelectedItem(i)" I will add it to the sample above

Comment: That  code will not compile.  Using `Dim i` and `For i ...` in the same scope will result in *Variable 'i' hides a variable...* and comparing `SelectedItem` (an object) to various strings wont compile using `Option Strict`

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks I forgot to remove the second declaration

Comment: Still wont compile and doesnt really answer the question.  `i want the code to work even if i didn't have to choose or highlight any of the item in the listbox`  So, the OP wants the code to magically do something at sometime based on the contents of the ListBox....but if there is nothing highlighted, then `SelectedItems` will be empty (hence the NRE)

Comment: the code running good now. just need another 's' on the 
 Select case Listbox1.SelectedItem(i)
Thank you guys

Comment: Glad to be able to help  :)